# The following assertion was thrown during performLayout(): RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size duringlayout

Tags: flutter, dart

I get this error when running the following code. I don't know what's wrong

> ```
> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
> RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size duringlayout
> ```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nle_app/models/stall.dart';
import 'package:nle_app/constants/colors.dart';

class StallInfo extends StatelessWidget {
  final stall = Stall.generateRestaurant();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      stall.name,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.4),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              stall.label,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            )),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    stall.logoUrl,
                    width: 80,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  stall.desc,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.star_outline,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '${stall.score}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 15),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

"This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big
as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own
size."

But I don't know where this error is coming from

"The constraints that applied to the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox were:

```
BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=600.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)"
```

"The exact size it was given was:

```
Size(600.0, Infinity)"
```

Comment: failed to reproduce the error,you can  try with `flutter clean` and rebuild the app.

Comment: Please can you answer this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75036155/my-widgets-arent-showing-rendering-on-my-home-screen @YeasinSheikh